# Opencms in Java

Tags: tomcat

I have installed the OPENCMS in the Tomcat and I have configured it in eclipse. At first I was doing well but now it gives me error. I have the Tomcat version 7 and java 7. This is the error that I get:

Grave: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/opencms]] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1009) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:985) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/opencms] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [oracle.net.aso.C00->oracle.net.aso.C12->oracle.net.aso.C11->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object->java.lang.Object] at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2174) at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2120) at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1981) at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1942) at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1927) at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1332) at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888) at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5519) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) ... 10 more

sep 29, 2017 12:18:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR Grave: Error durante el despliegue del archivo C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.81\webapps\opencms.war de la aplicación web java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/opencms]] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1013) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:985) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: `Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies.` ... have you looked into the suggestions coming from your stack trace?

Comment: Yes, run configurations=> arguments:-Xss2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m.

Comment: However, when I give debug it still gives me error

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact issue today with a different app and it ended up being that oracle.net.aso.C00 was in multiple jars.

Found with following snippet of bash:

in the WEB-INF/lib folder run

```
for jar in $(ls *jar); do unzip -l $jar ; done | grep -P '(^Archive|oracle.net.aso.C00)'
```

which resulted in:

```
Archive:  com.springsource.oracle.jdbc-10.2.0.2.jar
      804  02-04-2009 13:18   oracle/net/aso/C00.class
...
Archive:  ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar
       683  02-02-2008 11:39   oracle/net/aso/C00.class
```

needed to remove one of the jars.